# Way to enter amount of products to purchase?

Tags: stripe-payments

Do I have to do this server side with a custom payment button instead of their (beautiful) default one? Or can I just do some logic with the javascript (`price`*`amount`) or will it not work with their custom token thingy they generate? I'm using their Java api with Google Appengine, if that makes  a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to the other posts, here's a concrete example of how I'm doing it.

On the 'pay now' page with the default button, pass in the amount. One way I'm doing this is from a form on a previous page.

Parse this amount, e.g.

```
<?php
...
$data_amount = $_POST['data_amount'];
...
?>
```

And then use this amount as a value in the JS script which actually process the charge

```
<script
   src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"   
   ...
   data-amount="<?php echo $data_amount; ?>"
    ...
</script>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can do whatever you like to implement the product / quantity / price calculations.  The Stripe API simply expects your server-side to make a "charge" passing the card (or customer) token, and supplying an amount and a currency.  (There are a bunch of optional parameters too ...)

The "token thingy" does not contain an information about the payment itself.

---

I've not attempted to use Stripe myself.  The above is based on a cursory (10 minute) reading of the documentation.  But there are copious examples that you can find via the Stripe "Documentation" menu, including (Java) examples of what you need to do on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

The quantity and any other information about the items being purchased are irrelevant to the payment gateway, in this case, stripe. All that matters is the payment method (e.g. "visa card ending in 1234"), the amount, the currency and the customer.

You don't have to use the stripe provided checkout methods, you can write your own. The stripe examples are extensive and include Java code, though really the concepts are harder than the code itself (and the concepts aren't that hard). The token represents the payment method/customer and has nothing to do with the amount being charged.

Answer (score 0):

As the other folks have mentioned, the token doesn't contain quantity/charge amount info. The charge amount goes into the charge object.

Now, as far as additional info, particularly if you're coming from the classic PayPal world where you have quantities and so forth, or even if not but your purpose requires the back-end to know the extra detail, most (but not all) Stripe objects allow you to store key-value pairs in the optional 'metadata'.

If you're rolling up a cost (particularly if you're doing tax or other computations to get the total) you'll probably want to stuff the essentials (quantity, unit price, tax, itemized list, etc) into that block to be able to sanity-check and/or extract the details later on in the processing flow.

The Stripe docs are quite well done; click 'Java' at the top of the example column and you'll get cut-and-paste examples (for the most part).